# Friendly battle card level cap

Tags: clash-royale

When you want to make a Friendly Battle with someone from clan, there are some Tournament rules which cap levels on your cards and king tower, it goes as folows:

- King level: 9
- Common level: 9
- Rare level: 7
- Epic level: 4
- Legendary level:1

And my question is: **If some of my card exceed cap, can I use it in battle?**
For example: I can upgrade my goblins to level 10, so could I use them in friendly battle? If so will their level reduced to level 9?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.
Cards/king exceeding the level cap can be used in a friendly/tournament game. Their level will just be downgraded to the cap for the duration of the battle.

Couldn't find any exact sources for this, but I have used level 9 commons in a friendly battle.

Comment: Just checked the replay as well. The troops I had a level 9 appeared at level 8 in the game.

Answer (score 0):

Your Cards *will* have a lower Level. Any Cards excedding the Tournament Caps will get a Level reduction.
**However, the Mirror might still create units excedding the Caps. Example: You can create Level 10 Minions in a Tournament using it. (Or Level 14 in normal matches.)**